# Custom composer autoload directory, loading multiple packages

Tags: php, laravel, package, composer-php, laravel-5

Im developing a group of packag within a Laravel 5 app.

all the packages have the following structure.

**Folder structure:**

`Vendor/Package/src`

**composer.json**

```
"autoload": {
    "psr-4": {
        "Vendor\\Package\\": "src/"
    }
},
```

I would like to be able to have a separate folder outside of the `vendors/` folder that contains the packages, under development. As they are the basis for the application. NOTE: These packages will not be downloaded through composer, just auto-loaded with composer.

e.g.

```
\Laravel-App
    \app
    \bootstrap
    \config
    \database
    \public
    ...
    \src
```

The `\src` directory containing all the packages mentioned above.

Comment: If all my packages did not have the `\src` directory inside them then it works... although i need that extra layer to the packages. I could include many namespaces in the psr-4 autoload although that seems arduous

Comment: Create another function to attack to [spl_autoload](http://php.net/manual/en/function.spl-autoload.php) that loads based upon the directives of the packages you are developing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not relevant that there is a composer.json inside each package, because the are not managed by composer (, yet). Their autoload definition will only be used for an autoload dump by Composer, if the package is installed/updated.
Here there are not handled by Composer, just sitting around in a folder.

There are multiple ways of solving the autoloading problem.
You could:

- use the PHP autoload functions to register your own autoloader (during bootstrap)
- use Laravel's Autoloader to add the path to these packages (during app bootstrap, somewhere after laravel autoloader init)
- use Composer's Autoloader to add the paths to these packages (during app bootstrap, after Composer init)
- but the easiest way would be to define the mapping in the autoload section of the `composer.json` file of your main application. Then they will be included in the dumped autoloader, after install or update of your Composer managed dependencies.